# Automatically close oldest buffers?

Tags: buffers

I needed to edit a lot of files recently for a small change in each file.  To get to each file, I browsed through NERDtree and opened one file after another.  As I opened more and more files, I noticed that my memory usage grew a LOT.  Closing vim gave me a lot of memory back.

I have quite a few plugins installed, but I'm thinking that the reason my memory usage grew so drastically was due to the number of buffers I had open after a few edits.

Is there a way to limit the number of buffers that vim allows to be open at one time, automatically closing old buffers with respect to editing time?

Answer (score 7):

Let's solve the problem, not treat the symptoms. Vim shouldn't normally use large amounts of memory. It would be best isolate the issue. Some tips to help find the culprit:

- Disable plugins (use a binary search to make it faster)
- Reduce your `~/.vimrc` down to see if anything in there is the problem
- Disable your `~/.vimrc` completely via `vim -u NONE`

Also see [How do I debug my vimrc file?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2003/how-do-i-debug-my-vimrc-file?s=1|0.9748)

If you find a memory bug with a plugin then contact the plugin developer. If you find a memory bug with Vim then submit a bug report with steps to reproduce the error. See `:h bugs`

Comment: +1; it should be possible to open a gazillion buffers in Vim at the same time and still be good. As long as you're not viewing the buffer (in a window, or "tab") it's not loaded in memory.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker, buffer variables and settings do not disappear when the buffer is not displayed in a window. If a plugin stores a lot of information for each buffer, as Peter suggested, then memory could be wasted (considering the end-user won't do anything more with the buffer). BTW: A plugin may not store data related to buffers in `b:variables` but in a `s:plugin[bufid]` if the plugin maintainer preferred to not pollute the public `b:` _"namespace"_. In this case, deleting the buffer won't necessarily collect all related variables/memory.

Answer (score 6):

The following should answer your question.

```
function! s:SortTimeStamps(lhs, rhs)
  return a:lhs[1] > a:rhs[1] ?  1
     \ : a:lhs[1] < a:rhs[1] ? -1
     \ :                        0
endfunction

function! s:Close(nb_to_keep)
  let saved_buffers = filter(range(0, bufnr('$')), 'buflisted(v:val) && ! getbufvar(v:val, "&modified")')
  let times = map(copy(saved_buffers), '[(v:val), getftime(bufname(v:val))]')
  call filter(times, 'v:val[1] > 0')
  call sort(times, function('s:SortTimeStamps'))
  let nb_to_keep = min([a:nb_to_keep, len(times)])
  let buffers_to_strip = map(copy(times[0:(nb_to_keep-1)]), 'v:val[0]')
  exe 'bw '.join(buffers_to_strip, ' ') 
endfunction

" Two ways to use it
" - manually
command! -nargs=1 CloseOldBuffers call s:Close(<args>)
" - or automatically
augroup CloseOldBuffers
  au!
  au BufNew * call s:Close(g:nb_buffers_to_keep)
augroup END
" and don't forget to set the option in your .vimrc
let g:nb_buffers_to_keep = 42
```

This is to be dropped into a plugin or in your vimrc config. Then, you'll have to choose how to use it.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure how to get the oldest buffers with respect to editing time, but one could, instead, try to close the oldest unedited buffers. Something like:

```
function CloseLast ()
    python <<EOF
import vim
N = 10
listed_buffers = [b for b in vim.buffers if b.options['buflisted'] and not b.options['modified']]
for i in range (0, len (listed_buffers) - N):
    vim.command (':bd' + str (listed_buffers[i].number))
EOF
endfunction

autocmd BufNew * call CloseLast()
```

Notes:

- `vim.buffers` is a list of every buffer opened in the current session, so it also includes unlisted buffers. It is not the same as the list returned by `:ls`.
- Therefore, we must filter out the hidden or deleted buffers. This can be checked using `options['buflisted']`.
- Similarly, `options['modified']` lets us check if the buffer is modified.
- `N` is the number of unmodified, listed buffers you want open.

Thanks to [Luc Hermitte's answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/2198/205) from which I learnt how to get the timestamps, you could use the following instead, to get the oldest inactive kicked out first:

```
listed_buffers = (b for b in vim.buffers if b.options['buflisted'] and not b.options['modified'])
oldest_buffers = sorted (listed_buffers, key = lambda b: eval('getftime("' + b.name + '")'))
for i in range (0, len (oldest_buffers) - N):
    vim.command (':bd' + str (oldest_buffers[i].number))
```

Comment: You don't need python. Vim is more than enough: `:let buffers = filter(range(0, bufnr('$')), 'buflisted(v:val) && ! getbufvar(v:val, "&modified")')` + `:exe 'bw '.join(buffers, ' ')`

Comment: @LucHermitte True, but it's not a question of *need*. I'm just not familiar enough with Vimscript. IIRC `bw`'s help says you shouldn't use it "unless you know what you're doing". I don't. :)

Comment: Old habits. I always use `:bw`, and never `:bd`. I've never seen the point of deleting almost everything from a buffer, but not actually everything.